# How to disable automatic copy when selecting text from the keyboard?

Tags: clipboard

I've noticed that in Ubuntu 13.10 selecting text with the *keyboard* automatically copies it to the clipboard. I don't mind this behavior with the mouse so much, but with the keyboard it really drives me nuts. How to disable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bah, it turns out that parcellite was the culprit. Uninstalled that sucker, now everything is back to normal.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved you problem and remember to have a look at parcellite's clipboard history, an important tool when you copy in a cascading manner without pasting.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it originates in Parcellite, but you don't necessarily have to uninstall it.
You can go to:
Preferences (default shortcut is Control+Alt+P) -> Behavior ; Un-check the "Use Primary (Selection)" checkbox.